# Python - Create object from JSON with optional key/value parameters

Tags: python, json

Trying to create objects based on name/value pairs obtained in JSON form

e.g.

```
json = {'name': 'ruby',
        'type': 'rare',
        'size': {'weight': '5', 'height': '2'}
       }
```

however the name/values can be optional. So it could also be of the form

```
json = {'name': 'saph',
        'size': {'height': '4'}
        #'type' and 'height' have been omitted
       }
```

I attempted

```
class Gem(object):
    def __init__(self, **params):
        self.name = params['name']
        self.type = params['type']
        self.size = params['size']

gem = Gem(**json)
```

but it is expecting all parameters to be available.

I want to eventually be able to access properties of the object, e.g.

```
print(gem.name) #prints 'ruby'
print(gem.type) #prints 'rare'
```

Comment: Do you expect `gem.name` to be defined if `json` has no `name` entry?  If so, what default value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `get()` with a default value:

```
self.type = params.get('type', '')
```

### Update

A more elegant way of achieving this would be to use the combination of the packages `attrs` and `cattrs`. Install them with `pip` (*the minimal version of `cattrs` is **important***):

```
pip install attrs
pip install 'cattrs>=1.0.0rc0'
```

Then define your class as an `attrs` dataclass (`cattrs` doesn't support Python 3.7's standard dataclasses yet, which is why we use `attrs`):

```
In [1]: import attr

In [2]: import cattr

In [3]: @attr.s(auto_attribs=True) 
   ...: class Gem: 
   ...:     name: str = None 
   ...:     type: str = None  # Not a good name since it's a keyword, but I'm building upon the structure in the question
   ...:     size: str = None
```

And finally to construct an instance from a dictionary (which you possibly parsed from a JSON):

```
In [4]: cattr.structure({'name': 'saph', 
   ...:         'size': {'height': '4'} 
   ...:         #'type' and 'height' have been omitted 
   ...:        }, Gem)
Out[4]: Gem(name='saph', type=None, size="{'height': '4'}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access undefined key `type` when you are doing this `self.type = params['type']`.

This will throw `KeyError`.

You might want to use:

```
self.type = params.get('type', '') #sets self.type to '' empty string
self.type = params.get('type') #sets self.type to None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Gem(object):
    def __init__(self, **params):
        self.name = params['name'] if 'name' in params else None
        self.type = params['type'] if 'type' in params else None
        self.size = params['size'] if 'size' in params else None

gem = Gem(**json)
```

I would first check if the key is there if not leave it as `None`